# Get a Value frm SQL Server in timer c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, timer

I am trying to generate a custom Events in C# based on values from my database, whenever a values reaches a certain limit (lets say 0)
I have successfully done that in a Window service, I constantly monitor my DB and the moment value reaches this limit, I generate an Event in C#

Now there is a tweak in this approach that I need to generate event if the value stays "0" for 5 seconds. How I am Planning to do it create a List row, so whenever a value reaches 0, I insert in that List, Start the timer in background for that row. After 5 seconds I need to get value again from DB , if It is still 0, then only generate an event.

I was wondering if this is the right approach to counter my problem or is there any efficient/easier way also to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would store for each value a `DateTime.UtcNow` (maybe in a `ConcurrentDictionary<Row, DateTime>`). Then a second thread, timer, task, etc. could regularly iterate over this dictionary (maybe once per second) and check if the time for a specific row passes by and then raise the event for the given row.

In the meantime the original DB watcher could update that dictionary whenever he sees some changes, either by updating the time stamp or add, remove a row.